# Why doesn't ObjectContext.DetectChanges reset State to Unchanged?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, objectcontext

I'm having a little trouble understanding what DetectChanges does in this code (using EF 4.3):

```
using (var context =new BreakAwayContext())
{
var f = context.Destinations.First();
Console.WriteLine(context.Entry(f).State);
f.Name = "something";
Console.WriteLine(context.Entry(f).State);
context.Entry(f).Property(x => x.Name).CurrentValue =
    context.Entry(f).Property(x => x.Name).OriginalValue;
context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
Console.WriteLine(context.Entry(f).State);
}
```

What I see is 
    Unchanged
    Modified
    Modified

Since I reset the value of Name to its original value, why doesn't DetectChanges realize that all the property values match the snapshot of original values and set State back to Unchanged ?
(I realize calling DetectChanges here may be redundant because I am accessing an Entry prior to calling it, but I wanted to see if it would fix State).

Answer (score 2):

The state could have been set manually to `Modified`, for example:

```
var f = new Destination { Name = "something" };
context.Entry(f).State = EntityState.Modified; // attaches to context implicitly

context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
```

EF will detect here that OriginalValue == CurrentValue. But if it would set the state to `Unchanged` because of that equality it would defeat the purpose of *forcing* the entity into state `Modified` - for whatever reason the developer wants that.

EF would have to track the whole history of changes how it came to state `Modified` to decide if it can safely reset the state to `Unchanged` or not. In your simple example it would be probably right to reset the state, but in the more general case... who knows. Maybe such a tracking of *all* changes (instead of only original and current state) is just too complex for a safe solution, so nobody did implement it.

Just a guess...

Comment: That sounds reasonable, can't argue with your logic! Thanks for the thought.